# Hibernate native sql query doesn't work properly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

```
 public ChatRoomUserHelper isUserSubscribe(){
    Transaction transaction = null;
    ChatRoomUserHelper userHelper = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        userHelper = (ChatRoomUserHelper) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CHATROOM_USERHELPER WHERE CHAT_ROOMNAME ='chatdlya3uuid' AND USER_NICKNAME ='nikita555' and STATUS = 'subscribe'").
                addEntity(ChatRoomUserHelper.class);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        if(transaction!=null){
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userHelper;
}
```

It's my method which return hardcoded ChatRoomUserHelper object .
It's my project POJO class ChatRoomUserHelper .

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "CHATROOM_USERHELPER")
 @Embeddable
 @XmlRootElement
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class ChatRoomUserHelper {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int id;
@Column(name = "CHAT_ROOMNAME")
private String chatRoomName;
@Column(name = "USER_NICKNAME")
private String userNickName;
@Column(name = "STATUS")
private String userStatus;

public ChatRoomUserHelper(String chatRoomName,String userNickName){
    this.chatRoomName = chatRoomName;
    this.userNickName = userNickName;
    this.userStatus = "subscribe";
}

public ChatRoomUserHelper(){}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getChatRoomName() {
    return chatRoomName;
}

public void setChatRoomName(String chatRoomId) {
    this.chatRoomName = chatRoomId;
}

public String getUserNickName() {
    return userNickName;
}

public void setUserNickName(String userNickName) {
    this.userNickName = userNickName;
}

public String getUserStatus() {
    return userStatus;
}

public void setUserStatus(String userStatus) {
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
}
```

}
        [My Table with rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zShqw.png)
When i execute this method in IntellijIdea and MySQL workbench it works fine.

[MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfkht.png)

But when i use this method in program it don't want to work as i want and rolling back

I know that problem not in initializing Session Factory and so on , because all other stuff works fine. Problem in this query but i don't know how to fix this issue

```
   2016-04-18 13:24:52 DEBUG TransactionImpl:51 - begin
   2016-04-18 13:24:52 DEBUG TransactionImpl:86 - rolling back
   2016-04-18 13:25:14 DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:49 -     Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

It's all log's which i get

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this line instead:

```
userHelper = (ChatRoomUserHelper) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CHATROOM_USERHELPER c WHERE c.CHAT_ROOMNAME ='chatdlya3uuid' AND c.USER_NICKNAME ='nikita555' and c.STATUS = 'subscribe'").addEntity("c", ChatRoomUserHelper.class);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help me (

Comment: can you share the `StackTrace` catched here ?